# Disconnected displays after recent update

Tags: arch-linux, x, optimus

I've googled for hours, but still can't start gui on displays
Xorg.0.log

```
[  1546.586] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-1835.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[  1546.586] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1546.586] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[  1546.586] Current Operating System: Linux archlinux 5.1.3-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 16 20:59:36 UTC 2019 x86_64
[  1546.586] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=49d5cc49-ef4c-4220-8cf5-a44e5b087523 rw cryptdevice=UUID=3c329fd2-802f-4661-be14-67238b6d71f7:cr root=/dev/mapper/cr quiet
[  1546.586] Build Date: 27 February 2019  04:04:00PM
[  1546.587]  
[  1546.587] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[  1546.587]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1546.587] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1546.587] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon May 20 13:01:49 2019
[  1546.587] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1546.587] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1546.587] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1546.587] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1546.587] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1546.587] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1546.587] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1546.587] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1546.587] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1546.587] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  1546.587] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1546.587] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[  1546.587]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1546.587] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[  1546.587]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1546.587] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[  1546.587]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1546.587] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1546.587]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1546.587] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1546.587]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1546.587] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF
[  1546.587] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1546.587] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1546.587] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1546.587]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1546.587]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[  1546.587]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  1546.587]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1546.587] (++) using VT number 1

[  1546.587] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[  1546.588] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1546.589] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1546.589] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" setting /dev/dri/card0 as PrimaryGPU
[  1546.589] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:0) 8086:3e9b:1043:1021 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe3000000/16777216, 0x40000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1546.589] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:1c8d:1043:180e rev 161, Mem @ 0xe4000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  1546.590] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[  1546.590] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1546.590] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1546.590] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1546.590]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1546.590]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1546.590] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card0
[  1546.590]    loading driver: nvidia
[  1546.590] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1546.590] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1546.590] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1546.590] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[  1546.591] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[  1546.591] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
[  1546.591] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1546.591] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  1546.591] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  1546.591] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1546.591]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  1546.591]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1546.591] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[  1546.591] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
[  1546.591] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1546.591] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[  1546.591] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[  1546.591] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1546.591] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1546.591] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1546.591] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1546.591]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[  1546.591]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1546.591]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1546.591] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1546.591] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[  1546.591] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1546.591] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1546.591] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[  1546.591] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1546.591] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  430.14  Tue May  7 20:03:40 CDT 2019
[  1546.591] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  1546.591] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1546.600] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  1546.600] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  1546.600] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  1546.601] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1546.601]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1546.601]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1546.601] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[  1546.601] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[  1546.601] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[  1546.601] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1546.601]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1546.601]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1546.601] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[  1546.601] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[  1546.601] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[  1546.601] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  1546.601] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[  1546.601] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1546.601] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[  1546.601] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1546.601] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1546.601] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card0
[  1546.601] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
[  1546.601] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[  1546.601] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[  1546.601] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[  1546.601] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[  1546.604] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1546.604]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  1546.604]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1546.604] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  430.14  Tue May  7 20:02:40 CDT 2019
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[  1546.826] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1050 (GP107-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 4194304 kBytes
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 86.07.4c.00.48
[  1546.826] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[  1546.826] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[  1546.826] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[  1546.826] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[  1546.826] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(0): No enabled display devices found; starting anyway because
[  1546.826] (--) NVIDIA(0):     AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration is enabled
[  1546.826] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[  1546.826] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
[  1546.826] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[  1546.826] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[  1546.826] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[  1546.826] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  1546.826] (II) Unloading modesetting
[  1546.827] (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[  1546.827] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[  1546.829] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[  1546.846] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[  1546.850] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[  1546.850] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[  1546.850] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse disabled
[  1546.850] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[  1546.850] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "PrimaryGPU" is not used
[  1546.850] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[  1546.850] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1546.850] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[  1546.850] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[  1546.850] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[  1546.850] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension Present
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[  1546.851] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[  1546.851] (II) GLX: Another vendor is already registered for screen 0
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[  1546.851] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[  1546.852] (II) Initializing extension NV-GLX
[  1546.852] (II) Initializing extension NV-CONTROL
[  1546.872] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[  1546.872] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1546.872] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[  1546.872] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[  1546.873] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1546.873]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 0.28.2
[  1546.873]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1546.873]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[  1546.873] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1546.873] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1546.873] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  1546.873] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1546.873] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1546.873] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  1546.873] (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
[  1546.889] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3"
[  1546.889] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  1546.890] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1546.890] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  1546.890] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[  1546.890] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1546.890] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1546.890] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[  1546.890] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1546.890] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1546.890] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1546.890] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[  1546.890] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1546.891] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1546.891] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  1546.891] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[  1546.922] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2/event2"
[  1546.922] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  1546.923] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1546.923] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  1546.923] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[  1546.923] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1546.923] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[  1546.923] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[  1546.923] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[  1546.923] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1546.924] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1546.924] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[  1546.924] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[  1546.949] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[  1546.949] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[  1546.950] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1546.950] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[  1546.951] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN Touchscreen (/dev/input/event5)
[  1546.951] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
[  1546.951] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ELAN Touchscreen'
[  1546.951] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: always reports core events
[  1546.951] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[  1546.951] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1546.952] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: is tagged by udev as: Tablet
[  1546.958] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: tablet 'ELAN Touchscreen' unknown to libwacom
[  1546.958] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: device is a tablet
[  1546.958] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: device removed
[  1547.016] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/0003:04F3:2706.0001/input/input10/event5"
[  1547.016] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ELAN Touchscreen" (type: TABLET, id 9)
[  1547.017] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: is tagged by udev as: Tablet
[  1547.024] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: tablet 'ELAN Touchscreen' unknown to libwacom
[  1547.024] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: device is a tablet
[  1547.024] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN Touchscreen (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  1547.024] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.024] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.024] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN Touchscreen (/dev/input/event6)
[  1547.024] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
[  1547.024] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ELAN Touchscreen'
[  1547.024] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: always reports core events
[  1547.024] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[  1547.024] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.025] (II) event6  - ELAN Touchscreen: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[  1547.025] (II) event6  - ELAN Touchscreen: device is a touch device
[  1547.025] (II) event6  - ELAN Touchscreen: device removed
[  1547.082] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/0003:04F3:2706.0001/input/input11/event6"
[  1547.082] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ELAN Touchscreen" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 10)
[  1547.082] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1547.082] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1547.082] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1547.083] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1547.084] (II) event6  - ELAN Touchscreen: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[  1547.084] (II) event6  - ELAN Touchscreen: device is a touch device
[  1547.085] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN Touchscreen (/dev/input/mouse1)
[  1547.085] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.085] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.086] (II) config/udev: Adding input device FiiO DigiHug USB Audio (/dev/input/event7)
[  1547.086] (**) FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.086] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'FiiO DigiHug USB Audio'
[  1547.086] (**) FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: always reports core events
[  1547.086] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[  1547.086] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.088] (II) event7  - FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.088] (II) event7  - FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: device is a keyboard
[  1547.088] (II) event7  - FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: device removed
[  1547.162] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2.2/1-13.2.2:1.0/0003:1852:7022.0002/input/input15/event7"
[  1547.162] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "FiiO DigiHug USB Audio" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[  1547.167] (II) event7  - FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.167] (II) event7  - FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: device is a keyboard
[  1547.169] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard (/dev/input/event8)
[  1547.169] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.169] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard'
[  1547.169] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1547.169] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[  1547.169] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.173] (II) event8  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.173] (II) event8  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  1547.173] (II) event8  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device removed
[  1547.202] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2.3/1-13.2.3:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B20.0003/input/input16/event8"
[  1547.203] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[  1547.207] (II) event8  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.207] (II) event8  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  1547.209] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard (/dev/input/event9)
[  1547.209] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.209] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard'
[  1547.209] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1547.209] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[  1547.209] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.213] (II) event9  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.213] (II) event9  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  1547.214] (II) event9  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device removed
[  1547.242] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2.3/1-13.2.3:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B20.0004/input/input17/event9"
[  1547.242] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[  1547.247] (II) event9  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.247] (II) event9  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  1547.249] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control (/dev/input/event10)
[  1547.249] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.249] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control'
[  1547.249] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: always reports core events
[  1547.249] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[  1547.249] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.253] (II) event10 - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.253] (II) event10 - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
[  1547.254] (II) event10 - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: device removed
[  1547.282] (II) libinput: Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: needs a virtual subdevice
[  1547.282] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2.3/1-13.2.3:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B20.0004/input/input18/event10"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[  1547.283] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control" (type: MOUSE, id 14)
[  1547.283] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1547.283] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1547.283] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1547.283] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1547.287] (II) event10 - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.287] (II) event10 - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
[  1547.289] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard (/dev/input/event11)
[  1547.289] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.289] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.291] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard (/dev/input/event12)
[  1547.291] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.291] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.293] (II) config/udev: Adding input device COMPANY USB Device (/dev/input/event13)
[  1547.293] (**) COMPANY USB Device: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  1547.293] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'COMPANY USB Device'
[  1547.293] (**) COMPANY USB Device: always reports core events
[  1547.293] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event13"
[  1547.293] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.352] (II) event13 - COMPANY USB Device: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1547.353] (II) event13 - COMPANY USB Device: device is a pointer
[  1547.353] (II) event13 - COMPANY USB Device: device removed
[  1547.416] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2.4/1-13.2.4:1.0/0003:09DA:FC7C.0005/input/input21/event13"
[  1547.416] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "COMPANY USB Device" (type: MOUSE, id 15)
[  1547.416] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1547.416] (**) COMPANY USB Device: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1547.416] (**) COMPANY USB Device: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1547.416] (**) COMPANY USB Device: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1547.476] (II) event13 - COMPANY USB Device: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1547.476] (II) event13 - COMPANY USB Device: device is a pointer
[  1547.478] (II) config/udev: Adding input device COMPANY USB Device (/dev/input/mouse2)
[  1547.478] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.478] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.479] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V (/dev/input/event16)
[  1547.479] (**) USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.479] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V'
[  1547.479] (**) USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: always reports core events
[  1547.479] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event16"
[  1547.479] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.482] (II) event16 - USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.482] (II) event16 - USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: device is a keyboard
[  1547.482] (II) event16 - USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: device removed
[  1547.562] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/input/input26/event16"
[  1547.562] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V" (type: KEYBOARD, id 16)
[  1547.566] (II) event16 - USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.566] (II) event16 - USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: device is a keyboard
[  1547.567] (II) config/udev: Adding input device GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad (/dev/input/event15)
[  1547.567] (**) GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[  1547.567] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad'
[  1547.567] (**) GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: always reports core events
[  1547.567] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event15"
[  1547.568] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.679] (II) event15 - GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[  1547.686] (II) event15 - GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[  1547.686] (II) event15 - GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: device removed
[  1547.749] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-GDX1505:00/0018:27C6:01F1.0007/input/input24/event15"
[  1547.749] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 17)
[  1547.751] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1547.751] (**) GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1547.751] (**) GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1547.751] (**) GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1547.753] (II) event15 - GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[  1547.763] (II) event15 - GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[  1547.764] (II) config/udev: Adding input device GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse3)
[  1547.764] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.764] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.764] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event18)
[  1547.764] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.764] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.765] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event17)
[  1547.765] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.765] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Asus WMI hotkeys'
[  1547.765] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[  1547.765] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event17"
[  1547.765] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.766] (II) event17 - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.766] (II) event17 - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[  1547.766] (II) event17 - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
[  1547.829] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input27/event17"
[  1547.829] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 18)
[  1547.832] (II) event17 - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.832] (II) event17 - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[  1547.833] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[  1547.833] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.833] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[  1547.833] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[  1547.833] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[  1547.833] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1547.835] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.835] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  1547.838] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[  1547.882] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4"
[  1547.882] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
[  1547.885] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1547.885] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  1547.888] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event14)
[  1547.888] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1547.888] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1547.890] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1547.890] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control'
[  1547.890] (**) Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: always reports core events
[  1547.890] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[  1547.890] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[  1547.890] (II) libinput: Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: is a virtual subdevice
[  1547.890] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2.3/1-13.2.3:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B20.0004/input/input18/event10"
[  1547.890] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 20)
[  1547.891] (EE) Failed to open authorization file "/var/run/sddm/{faf6700a-1242-48de-b98d-683fc4611caf}": No such file or directory
[  1548.874] (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
[  1548.909] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[  1548.936] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[  1548.959] (II) event5  - ELAN Touchscreen: device removed
[  1549.016] (II) event6  - ELAN Touchscreen: device removed
[  1549.082] (II) event7  - FiiO DigiHug USB Audio: device removed
[  1549.136] (II) event8  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device removed
[  1549.163] (II) event9  - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard: device removed
[  1549.189] (II) event13 - COMPANY USB Device: device removed
[  1549.242] (II) event16 - USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V: device removed
[  1549.296] (II) event15 - GDX1505:00 27C6:01F1 Touchpad: device removed
[  1549.349] (II) event17 - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
[  1549.402] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[  1549.429] (II) event10 - Corsair Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Keyboard Consumer Control: device removed
no
```

If I downgrade xorg server to 1.19 version, there is no error

```
1547.891] (EE) Failed to open authorization file "/var/run/sddm/{faf6700a-1242-48de-b98d-683fc4611caf}": No such file or directory
```

But all displays are still disconnected
lshw

```
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:163 memory:e4000000-e4ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:e5000000-e507ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e3000000-e3ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Xorg

```
Section "Module"
    Load "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "1:0:0"
#    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection
```

Xsetup

```
#!/bin/sh
# Xsetup - run as root before the login dialog appears
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

I have the same problem using lightdm and sddm

I've configured xorg.conf using archliux documentation, and this configuration was working while I've updated today.
What is wrong?